# Flash Movie not loaded after site migration

Tags: flash

@ http://tinyurl.com/6mjd2nj I have a site that was just moved to a new server due to a faulty raid. Now even though all files and database have been moved the Flash movie won't load slash play. The Flash movie is on the server and so is index.html and AC_RunActiveContent.js and all needed files as far as I can see. Also did not find any errors that could relate to the issue. So what is the issue?

Comment: It could be that the new server is not configured correctly to serve the MIME type(s) needed for the Flash and/or related files, like "application/x-shockwave-flash" for swf files and "video/x-flv" for flv files, if you use those.

Comment: Just asked my hoster. Will wait for their reply. Thanks for the tip Lars

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö: the file is loaded (it is a 344 kb swf). What should eventually do (eg. call a server side script)?

Comment: Yes, the swf file is loaded, but the file seems to be corrupted somehow (a swf analyzing tool reports that it "doesn't satisfy Adobe SWF File Format Specification"). rhand, maybe you could try to replace the file, by uploading a new copy?

Comment: The AC_RunActiveContent.js got corrupted. Had to be reloaded. Hoster reloaded some other files as well. All good now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comment the AC_RunActiveContent.js got corrupted during transfer as well as some other files. All good now.